# Google Visualization API : Object function (){return s; } has no method 'isEnabled'

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Visualization API to display charts. It used to work well since one year or even more, but since this morning I have a error message :

```
Object function (){return s; } has no method 'isEnabled'
```

This is an example of the Javascript code i'm using :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($(this.options._divId));

chart.draw(data, { width: this.options._width, height:this.options._height, legend:'bottom', chartArea: {left:38,top:30, width:"90%",height:"70%"} });
```

I don't find more information about the error. Is there anyone who have the same error ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and looking at [Google Charts release Notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes?hl=it#whatsnew) they released a new version on August 27, 2013.
I'm currently looking on the changes needed to fix the old code in order  to make it work with the new version.

Edit: i've found a quick workaround to make the graphs work again, specifying an older version of the apis:

```
google.load('visualization','1.0',{'packages':["corechart"]},{'language':'en'});
```

The trick here is forcing the use of the '1.0' api version instead of the default 1.1.

Edit2: i've created a ticket for this problem:
[Issue 1302 - google-visualization-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1302)

Comment: This is not really an answer, please make your answer more constructive

Comment: Thank you for the link. I try to find a way to resolve it too.